# Seeking for help with complex conjugate of bra|ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, complex-numbers

I have 2 vectors: $$|a\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 2+i & 2+2i\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ |b\rangle=\begin{pmatrix} 1+i & 1+2i\end{pmatrix}$$
So basically I need to show that $$\langle a| b\rangle=\langle b| a\rangle^*$$

Attempt of solution:
So when I multiply matrices I get for left side: $$\langle a| b\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}  2-i \\ 2-2i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1+i & 1+2i\end{pmatrix}=(2-i)(1+i)+(2-2i)(1+2i)=2+2i-i+1+2+4i-2i+4=9+3i$$ for the right side I have:
$$\langle b| a\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}  1-i \\ 1-2i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2+i & 2+2i\end{pmatrix}=(1-i)(2+i)+(1-2i)(2+2i)=2+i+2-2i+1+2i-4i+4=9-3i$$
But I expected to get (I have an answer given by professor) $\langle a| b\rangle=9-3i$ and$\langle b| a\rangle=9+3i$.

So I dont know, did I make a mistake, or professor?

Comment: Even though i showed that left side is complex conjugate of right side, but still confused

Comment: Shouldn't your ket be column vectors and the bra be row vectors?

Comment: Thormund, you are right. Kostya Komless, bra is row vector, ket is column vector. However Kostya, your answer is correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks to you people^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bra should be a row vector and the ket should be a column vector. If you redo in that way, you will get the required answer.

Comment: Thank you for an answer I will try to do that